# Netwox tool#78: Error 4081

Tags: security, virtualbox-networking, hacking

I am trying to run Netwox tool 78 on Ubuntu 18.04 and also tried on Ubuntu Osboxes image; but, I am getting following errors:

```
$ sudo netwox 78 --filter 10.161.25.252 Error 4081 :
error in pcap_compile()  hint: errno = 22 = Invalid argument  hint:
can't parse filter expression: syntax error osboxes@osboxes:~$ sudo
netwox 78 --filter "10.161.25.252" Error 4081 : error in
pcap_compile()  hint: errno = 22 = Invalid argument  hint: can't parse
filter expression: syntax error osboxes@osboxes:~$
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [project's site](http://ntwox.sourceforge.net/): "This project reached its End Of Maintenance in 2007"

Looks like a pretty broken and not well documented program, IMNSHO. Your error seems to be some mysterious bug in the program. I got the same error message. Not sure why this is even included in the repositories.

There is a little bit of documentation in `/usr/share/doc/netwox`.

You can try reading either `problemusageunix.txt.gz` or `toollist.txt.gz` with the following commands:

```
zcat /usr/share/doc/netwox/problemusageunix.txt.gz
zcat /usr/share/doc/netwox/toollist.txt.gz
```

A quick glance through those docs doesn't show me anything pertaining to your error. Good luck.

Comment: I think its not executable on Ubuntu but the same syntax works on Kali Linux. I tried this even on my Ubuntu distribution 18.04.

Comment: @user2994783 It did look like an interesting program...I tried it on 18.04, 19.10 and a Mint 19.2box  and got the same error across all of them.

Answer (score 0):

So I found this fix for the problem. Checkout this page for the documentation [tcpdump manpages](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-filter.7.html)

So in effect, to specify the source and destination IP addresses, you use **dst** for destination or **src** for source

```
sudo netwox 78 --device "Eth0" --filter "dst 10.0.2.4" --ips "10.0.2.5"
```